# Colima runtime on macOS: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ : No such file or directory (os error 2)

Tags: docker, macos, colima

I am getting the error "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/": No such file or directory (os error 2)" when trying to run a Docker container on macOS using the Colima runtime.

I have tried adding "storage-driver": "devicemapper" to my /Users/username/.docker/daemon.json file, but this did not fix the issue.

Here are the details of my setup:

Machine: macOS 12.4 (Monterey) with the arm64 architecture
Colima runtime: 0.5.5
Docker client: 23.0.2
Docker server: 20.10.20
Here are the steps I am taking to reproduce the issue:

run the docker image

```
docker run --rm -d -ti ubuntu:22.04 bash
```

Run the following command to inspect the image:

```
docker inspect image-id -f '{{.GraphDriver.Data.LowerDir}}'
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/image-id-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/image-id/diff
```

Run the following command to list the contents of the /var/lib/docker/overlay2 directory:

```
ls /var/lib/docker/overlay2
```

If you see the following error message, then you are experiencing the same issue as me:

ls: cannot access /var/lib/docker/overlay2: No such file or directory

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps, but none of them have worked:

- I have restarted my machine, docker
- I have restarted  Colima.
- I have run command `docker system prune -a`
- I have added "storage-driver": "devicemapper" to my /Users/username/.docker/daemon.json

Can anyone help me to troubleshoot this issue?

I tried

```
ls /var/lib/docker/overlay2/
```

And I expect list of layers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, after digging and checking with Colima maintainers.

So the takeaway is that I need to run `colima ssh`

everything is inside the Colima instance not my MacOS host, that was tricky